# Wordpress selecting a page

Tags: wordpress

i'm trying to load content specific to a page. I know using `<?php if(is_front_page() ) : ?>` is for the front page how would I choose a page like /teams/ or /groups/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if(is_page('teams') ) : ?>
```

or

```
<?php if(is_page('teams','groups') ) : ?>
```

See for more:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page